# Can't add widget in Android Studio when in a google maps activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view

I am having real problem putting in widgets by text or by the drag and drop function in a google maps activity.

Putting in widgets by text or by the drag and drop function in other activities work well but not in google maps activity where this doesn't work at all.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by maps activity you mean the default one that gets generated when you choose Google->Google Maps Activity template, then simply go to layout file and wrap fragment there with some Layout, for example FrameLayout.

Basically turn this:

```
<fragment
   ... 
/>
```

Into this:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <fragment
       ... 
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

And your drag'n'drop functionality for adding widgets will be restored.